# Laravel 8.38 validation issue, max file size. RuntimeException: The file {public path} cannot be opened. in file Psr17Factory.php on line 46

Tags: php, validation, laravel-8

Created the file validation as (for test purpose it is 5kb)

```
'file': "max:5|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,pdf,txt,doc,docx,mp4"
```

There is a weird issue, as it is displaying a valid error on uploading **png**

```
...may not be greater than 5 kilobytes.
```

but on uploading **mp4** it is throwing following error

```
RuntimeException: The file {path-here}\public cannot be opened. in file 
{path-here}\vendor\nyholm\psr7\src\Factory\Psr17Factory.php on line 46
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open icons tray on right side of your windows.
2. left click on wamp icon.
3. click on PHP > PHP Settings > upload_max_filesize = (set the size to max 256 MB).

> You can also edit it in php.ini file in `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.37\bin\php.ini`
> [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcU85.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having same error when sending file via postman to server with **Laragon**(not wamp/xampp) tried setting up my upload_max_file but couldn't find luck. In the end, Running Laragon with **Run as Administrator** did work.